# 1990s (or earlier) book in which a human detective is hired by a vampire to find killer of vampires

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book in the early 1990s. It's been a while, so my details may be a bit fuzzy.

I recall that the setting was in the late 19th century and a human detective is approached by a vampire to investigate the deaths of vampires. It turns out that another vampire is killing his own kind.

That's about all I remember about the plot. I got it from the Science Fiction Book Club back in the day, and I think it was one that got shipped to me, because I didn't send the card back in time. It was entertaining though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Probably [*Those Who Hunt the Night*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Those_Who_Hunt_the_Night), by Barbara Hambly (1988).  Aside from my memory, I see that Wikipedia describes it thus in part:

> The 20th century is just under way, and somebody is killing the vampires of London. Against the wishes of his fellow undead, Simon Ysidro, oldest of the London vampires, seeks the assistance of Oxford professor James Asher, former spy for the British government. . . .  Asher's theory is that the killer must be a vampire himself, one able to remain awake and active in the daytime.

I added an edit to note that the ISFDB lists a SFBC edition, but for some reason that seemingly didn't go through:

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?288885

Comment: Nicely found! And welcome to the site.

Comment: That sure does sound like the answer.  I could definitely be wrong about the it being from SFBC, that's just where a bunch of books I was reading came from during that time. I checked my local library and they have a copy, so I'll check it out and see.  Thanks for solving a 20+ year mystery!